# java concurrency: CopyOnWriteArrayList strategy

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to understand `CopyOnWriteArrayList` into my code:

My code is:

```
public class AuditService {
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Audit> copyWrite;

    public void flush(Audit... audits) {
        Collection<Audit> auditCollection = Arrays.asList(audits);
        this.copyWrite.addAll(auditCollection);

        this.copyWrite.forEach(audit -> {
            try {
              // save audit object on database
              this.copyWrite.remove(audit);
            } catch (DataAccessException e) {
              // log it
            }

        });
    }
}
```

What this code do is:

1. First stores audits into a a buffer, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.
2. Tries to save an audit to database
3. When it's been stored, it's removed from buffer `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Others:

1. `AuditService` is a singleton class
2. `flush` method can be reached by several threads.

Questions:

1. I guess that `this.copyWrite.forEach(audit -> {...` can be reached at the same time by several threads: Does it mean a same audit object can be tried to be saved on database twice?
2. Each time a modification operation is made on `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, a new copy is populated on others threads? How is it populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `remove` is called, a new copy of the internal array backing the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is made. Future accesses to that list with accessor and mutator methods will have visibility on the update.

**However**, the method `CopyOnWriteArrayList#foreach` method iterates on the array which was available at the time it was called. This means all executions of the method `flush` which entered the `foreach` **prior to** any update on the list will iterate on a stale version of the array.

As such, during parallel executions of the method `flush`, the same `Audit` elements will be persisted more than once, and up to `d` times if `d` is the number of maximal concurrent executions of the method `flush`.

Another problem with the use of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` in this case is since a new copy is made for every call to `remove`, the complexity of your code is `d.n^2` where `n` is the length of the list and `d` defined above.

The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not the correct implementation to use here. There are multiple possible suitable designs possible. One of them is to use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` as follows [*]:

```
public void flush(Audit... audits) {
    Collection<Audit> auditCollection = Arrays.asList(audits);
    this.queue.addAll(auditCollection);

    Collection<Audit> poissonedAudits = new ArrayList<Audit>();
    Audit audit = null;
    while ((audit = this.queue.poll()) != null) {
       try {
          // save audit object on database
          queue.remove(audit);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
          // log it
          poissonedAudits.add(audit);
        }
    }
    this.queue.addAll(poissonedAudits);
}
```

The call to `LinkedBlockingQueue#poll()` is thread-safe and atomic. The same element can never be polled multiple times (as long as it isn't added to the queue more than once, cf [*]). Complexity is linear in `n`.

Two points to consider:

- Your collection of audit must not contain `null` elements, as this is forbidden for a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, because `null` is used to indicate the list is empty.
- You should take care not to use blocking methods such as `take` of `poll(timeout, unit)` to poll the queue.

[*] There has been a change in the `flush` method which new does not perform a copy of `Audit` elements. I am not sure whether there is a guarantee these elements are distinct if the `flush` method is called in parallel. If the array of `Audit` is the same for all invocations of `flush`, the queue should be populated only once, prior to any call to `flush`.

Comment: I edited your answer. Please could you take a look a commit it?

Comment: I've just realized you removed `Audits... audits` parameter. I've also read the `[*]` and I don't quite figure out what exactly do you mean. I've edited your post with my suggestions. Please, don't hesitate to make your thoughts.